# Computing kernel of a graded homomorpism in an algorithmic way

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings, computational-algebra, groebner-basis

For computing kernel of a module homomorphism we can use module-Grobner basis as described in notes talking about computing SyZyGies. But how can we compute kernel of a homomorphism between a graded rings? I was thinking that maybe I should consider the graded parts of the two rings as modules and then computing kernel of restriction of the graded homomorphism on them but then I have an infinite sequence of generators for these kernels, even if it be a right attempt then I should think about bringing out a finite generator for the main kernel. I somehow feel it's not a correct idea. Does anyone know how to compute these kernels? It is possible as for example Singular software compute defining ideal of Rees algebra which is kernel of a graded homomorphism, so there should be a computational method.

Comment: What do you mean by "compute" ?

Comment: @CaptainLama for example consider a hommorphism between two polynomial ring, for computing its kernel one can use Groebner basis and elimination which is a nice application of Groebner basis and one can see in many books about computational algebraic geometry or commutative algebra. Or the one I mentioned about SyZyGies. By computing I mean finding a generator explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look into the details but Tutorial 45: Homogeneous Maps and Toric Ideals in the book *Computational Commutative Algebra 2* by **Kreuzer and Robbiano** might be helpful.

In the tutorial they consider graded $K$-algebra homomorphisms of the form $$\phi \colon K[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I \longrightarrow K[y_1, \dots, y_m]/I'$$ where $I \subseteq K[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ and $I' \subseteq K[y_1, \dots, y_m]$ are ideals.

Comment: It solves the question for the $\mathbb{Z}^m$-graded rings graded by weight matrices. +1